# RowHeader styled table that sorts both rowHeader and data

Tags: java, swing

I have recently implemented the rowHeader Jtable via this example here: http://www.chka.de/swing/table/row-headers/JTable.html

Right now everything works great. However, when I tried making the data sortable using this function: table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true), this is where it goes wrong.

The rowHeader is not sorted the same way the table data is sorted. Has anyone has experience solving this? the data and rowHeader has to be sorted together!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, add the table header to a different part of your layout, as suggested in [*How to Use Tables: Adding a Table to a Container*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show).